# quotations in input python

Tags: python

When using Python3, and doing something as simple as

```
x=input("Enter your name: ")

print (x)
```

and trying to run it, the user would have to input their name as "Steve" rather than just Steve.

Is there a way around having to input with quotations?

Answer (score 11):

I think you're mistaken.  In Python 3, you *don't* need quotation marks:

```
localhost-2:~ $ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input("Enter your name:")
Enter your name:Steve
>>> x
'Steve'
```

You would in the olden days of Python 2, because `input` basically `eval`s what you give it:

```
>>> x = input("Enter your name:")
Enter your name:Steve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Steve' is not defined
>>> x = input("Enter your name:")
Enter your name:"Steve"
>>> x
'Steve'
```

and so you'd use `raw_input` instead:

```
>>> x = raw_input("Enter your name:")
Enter your name:Steve
>>> x
'Steve'
```

But in Python 3, `input` is what `raw_input` used to be, and so no quotation marks are necessary.

Comment: It may be my coding set up, but when I launch it using Python Launcher, and then it runs through terminal.app on my Mac, if I don't use quotations, it [fails](http://i.imgur.com/cfKPD.png?1).

But if run it while using IDLE, I don't need quotation marks.

Comment: @Greenlep: add `import sys`; `print(sys.version)` to the start of your program.  Pretty sure you won't see 3.*.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. Thank you, terminal has an outdated version of python… [2.7.1](http://i.imgur.com/5gKTm.png)

Thank you.